# Best way to insert control into tab order?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, tab-ordering

If there is an existing tab order on a large set of controls on a form, what is the easiest way to insert a control in the middle of that tab order without having to re-number the tab order of all the controls after the one inserted?

Comment: What have you tried? Duplicates: [Setting the TabIndex property of many form controls in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837752/setting-the-tabindex-property-of-many-form-controls-in-visual-studio), [Control Tab Order in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718463/control-tab-order-in-visual-studio-2010), [How can I to remove or reset the tab order in VS 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010564/how-can-i-to-remove-or-reset-the-tab-order-in-vs-2010) & [How to: Set the Tab Order on Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw.aspx)

Comment: may be duplicate. but i think its not intentionally duplicate post by user. It can be lack of searching. But nice question.

Comment: @Freelancer a good question requires research effort, which you can see when you move your mouse over the upvote button, so your comment contradicts itself.

Comment: you can try this addon. Disclaimer - I'm the suthor of this addon. http://codecanyon.net/item/winforms-tab-index-addin/4567358?WT.ac=category_thumb&WT.seg_1=category_thumb&WT.z_author=Rifky

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio has a tool for that. It allows you to click the taborder you want - by selecting the control in the order you want:

[image]

[image]

the blue boxes(with white numbers) are the current taborder, and white boxes are the new taborder.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but what toolbar is this? I don't seem to see that button.

Comment: Note, clicking on the form, `View -> Show Tab Order` works in VS2013. For people who don't have this toolbar enabled.

Comment: Nice dialog… unless you have ≈40 different widgets, and do care about the order for just a few, and the dialog sets `0` for the first widget  you clicked, and `0.0.16.17.0` for the second.

Comment: A picture paints a thousand words, thanks your screenshot helped me greatly :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to you.

```
(new TabOrderManager(this)).SetTabOrder(TabOrderManager.TabScheme.AcrossFirst);
```

Follow this link>

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8406/Automatic-Runtime-Tab-Order-Management-for-Windows